# A complex function integral

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I got a problem in an exam.
We need to caculate following limit:

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \int_{L_x}\frac{\cos z}{z^2+1} dz,$$
>   where $L_x$ is the line from $-x+2i$ to $x+2i$.

Of course we can calculate the integrals of the real part and imaginary part seperately. But it would be extremely complicated. I think it can't be the right solution since it wouldn't be done in the time of an exam.

Comment: You should look into your lecture notes and search for the residue theorem. Using this the integral is not that complicated

Comment: Substitute $z$ such that you have the integral on the real axis. You can notice that you then have a Fourier type integral.

Comment: There is nothing *very complicated* here. Just a standard exercise about the application of the residue theorem to $\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}$. You should add your attempts.

Answer (score 8):

First note that we can write

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{L_x}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+1}\,dz=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac12\int_{L_x}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\,dz+\frac12\int_{L_x}\frac{e^{-iz}}{z^2+1}\,dz\right)\tag 1$$

We can evaluate the limit of each of the integrals on the right-hand side of $(1)$ using the residue theorem.

---

For the first integral, we close the contour in the upper-half plane.  Inasmuch as neither pole is enclosed by the contour, we see that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac12\int_{L_x}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\,dz\right)=0$$

---

For the second integral, we close the contour in the lower-half plane.  Inasmuch as both poles are enclosed, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac12\int_{L_x}\frac{e^{-iz}}{z^2+1}\,dz\right)&=-\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{-iz}}{z^2+1}, z=\pm i\right)\\\\
& =-\pi i \left(\frac{e}{2i}+\frac{e^{-1}}{-2i}\right)\\\\
&=-\pi \sinh(1)
\end{align}$$

---

Putting it all together, we see that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{L_x}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+1}\,dz=-\pi \sinh(1)}$$

Comment: How to choose the proper contour?

Comment: Note $e^{+iz}$ decays in the upper-half plane and $e^{-iz}$ decays in the lower-half plane.

Comment: (+1) A coordinate effort is always the best. I am going to remove my previous comments.

Comment: Clearly I was way off, great answer +1

Comment: @Bacon Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Your justification that the first integral (with $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z}$) is zero is incomplete.  You have explained that the path integral around the loop is zero, but you have written that the path integral along the line segment is zero.  There's a step missing.  (In fact, you have written line segment integrals for both of your loop integrals.)  The same omission occurs in your second integral.  To avoid being mysterious : Why can you ignore the contribution from the semicircular arcs that you never mention in your displayed integrals?

Comment: Also, your work on the second integral supposes $x > 3/2$, (or some other lower bound, if you are imagining completing your line segments with something other than semicircles to make loops) but you do not say so.

Comment: @EricTowers  Is use of Jordan's Lemma a mystery?

Comment: @EricTowers $x\to \infty$ ... If you wish to post a solution that provides the details, then please feel free to do so.  I have left the details to the reader(s).  And evidently, that was enough for 9 up votes to date.  ;-))

Comment: I feel your answer is almost correct.  When you write $\int_{L_x}$ for integrals over a loop instead of a line, you have a defect.  Then, when you don't even *mention* Jordan's Lemma, it is not I creating the mystery.

Comment: @erictowers Eric, the equality is correct.  The reader (e.g., you) may fill in details that are elementary.  If you wish, then post a solution with the details that you covet herein.

Comment: @EricTowers  You down voted an answer that is correct and for which 9 others found useful.  That is a bit audacious!

Answer (score 4):

Let us consider a rectangle $\gamma_R$ with vertices at $-R,R,R+2i,-R+2i$, counter-clockwise oriented, with $R\gg 1$and $f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+1}$. By the ML lemma and the residue theorem

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\oint_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz &=& \int_{-R}^{+R}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+1}\,dz - \int_{-R+2i}^{R+2i}f(z)\,dz + o(1)\\&=& 2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=i\right)=\pi\cosh(1) \end{eqnarray*}$$
as $R\to +\infty$, hence in order to compute the given limit it is enough to compute
$$ \lim_{R\to +\infty}\int_{-R}^{+R}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+1}\,dz =\text{Re}\left[2\pi i\cdot \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1},z=i\right)\right]=\frac{\pi}{e}$$
to get:
$$ \lim_{R\to +\infty}\int_{-R+2i}^{R+2i}f(z)\,dz = \color{red}{-\pi\sinh(1)}.$$

Comment: (+1) It's always cool to see that two different approaches lead to the same result.